# Spring Boot @ConditionalOnProperty not seeing property override

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and an external library. The application imports the library. In the library a property is set with default value `true`. In the application I want to override this value. There is a `@Configuration` class in the library which is loaded conditionally based on the value of this property. The relevant classes are shown below:

Library's configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LibraryProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "com.foo", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class LibraryConfiguration {

    // Load the Beans

}
```

Library's application.properties:

```
com.foo.enabled = ${ENABLE_FOO:true}
```

Application's main class:

```
@Import(LibraryConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Appl.class, args);
    }

}
```

Application's application.properties:

```
com.foo.enabled = false
```

The property override from my application's properties file is not working; the configuration form the library is loaded. Is the annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty` evaluated *before* my application's properties are loaded to override those from the library?

Comment: AFAIK you should not name your properties file `application.properties` inside your starter, otherwise the order of configfile loading might affect which property overrides other properties. In your starter consider using a different name and add a @PropertySource(location to your properties file) to your autoconfiguration.

Comment: @helospark That did the trick. I didn't realize the properties file _name_ was important and could cause a clash. I must have missed this in the docs.